# Export certain cells only to PDF when a certain string/number is chosen in the drop downlist

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to export certain cells only to PDF when a choice is chosen in the drop box. I am not sure on what I need to do in the For Loop. I always get an empty PDF file when I am trying to export it. I believe I have put in the right if conditions but I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

```
Public Sub exportPDF()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim Answers As Double
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
On Error GoTo errHandler

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
 For Each Answer In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
 If myFile <> "False" And Answer.Value = "99" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & myFile

ElseIf myFile <> "False" And Answer.Value = "66" Then
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & myFile

Else
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & myFile
End if
Next Answer

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like you are running loop on only one cell. i.e "Range("A2")". You can start by running your code by pressing F8 (line by line execution) ....That will help you identify where and what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data it's hard to give a solution but i've given a try. There is no need to loop over a single cell you can just test that cell for the necessary value. Also i would put `option explicit` at the top this is to avoid using undeclared varables, error handle label not used properly so no point to keep it...you need to put the label at the bottom and provide some error handleing code for that to work. Exporting not too sure why you want to export that specific range  `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")` to me this does not export the whole page just part of it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub exportPDF()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant

myFile = "exported file.pdf"

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
 If Range("A2").Value = 99 Then

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & myFile

ElseIf Range("A2").Value = 66 Then 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & myFile

Else
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
'confirmation message with file info
MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & myFile
End If
'Next Answer

End Sub
```